# How to represent a filesystem in EF6

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-6

I need to represent a filesystem using EntityFramework 6. I have tried multiple ways of defining the relationships but I didn't found a way that worked.

So basically I have these 3 classes. (I only included the relevant properties)

Computer.cs

```
public class Computer
{
 public FileSystem FileSystem {get; set;}
}
```

FileSystem.cs

```
public class FileSystem
{
 public File RootFile {get; set; }
}
```

File.cs

```
public class File
{
 [Key]
 public int Id {get; set; }

 public FileSystem FileSystem {get; set; }

 public File Parent { get; set; }

 public List<File> children {get; set; }
}
```

How would I define the relationships of all this ?

I'm not really good at this as this is my first time doing something like that but I think there is:

- A One to Many relationship between a File and its children
- A Many to One relationship between a File and its FileSystem

thanks in advance.

Comment: *A Many to One relationship between a File and its FileSystem* -- That should be `public List<File> Files {get; set; }` in `FileSystem`, but I'm not sure if you still need `RootFile` then.

Comment: So I should add a list to my FileSystem class and maybe use a boolean in each file to check if it's the root file ?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't model root files at all.  A file system is a straightforward recursive data structure. if you walk up the tree until you find a note that doesn't have a parent then it's a root.  There's no need to be so specific.

Comment: Hey you're right, I think I'll just get a List of files and the Root file will have no parent. Thanks !

Comment: @AluanHaddad Using a root item can reduce duplicated code though, because you would need Add/Insert/Remove/etc. functions for both the file system and files

Comment: @REghZY You could use a common abstraction as  dotnet's `FileSystemInfo` does or you could use generics.